# I am able to deploy my lwc but I see a red line under lightningCommunity__Page_Layout target

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, experience-builder-page

Code for metadata file in lwc to give home page a custom layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>Hope Page Layout</masterLabel>
    <description>Telegram Home Page Layout</description>
    <targets>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page_Layout</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

On hovering over the page layout target line, I see the following error.

> Value '**lightningCommunity__Page_Layout**' is not in the enumeration
> list.
>
> It must be one of the following:
>
> - lightning__AppPage
> - lightning__HomePage
> - lightning__RecordPage
> - lightning__UtilityBar
> - lightning__FlowScreen
> - lightning__Tab
> - lightning__Inbox
> - lightningStatic__Email
> - lightningCommunity__Page
> - lightningCommunity__Default

Comment: update: Even sample code from the guide throws same error. What am I missing?

Comment: Deployed successfully for me (exact same `targets` as you pasted here). What's the context here - are you deploying to a sandbox, scratch org, etc? How are you deploying exactly (command used)?

Comment: I am deploying to my Dev org.  Right Click: SFDX: Deploy Source to Org

Comment: I am able to deploy without the pagelayout target, @KrisGoncalves

Comment: What's the api version in your `sfdx-project.json`? Version of your sfdx cli? have you created a LWR site already in that dev org? Or have you enabled [ExperienceBundle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_migrate_expbundle.htm) Metadata? `Setup --> Digital Experiences --> Settings -->  Enable ExperienceBundle Metadata API`

Comment: I see that if I ignore the vs error, I can deploy to org. I have just enabled the metadata api, sfdx-project api version is 52. sfdx-cli/7.110.0 win32-x64 node-v14.17.3

Comment: @KrisGoncalves i no longer receive error after enabling metadata api and reloading vs code. Thanks

Comment: @KrisGoncalves Error persists. Guess vs just took time

Comment: where is this error displaying from? The `problems` tab? I'd [edit] your question with more specifics on what is flagging it as an issue as it sounds like you said there's no issue deploying the LWC with the target (which answers your questions, it's not deprecated).

Comment: Hey @HarshPrakashAgarwal, Are you able to resolve this issue? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @DhanikLalSahni the problem was encountered due to extensions checking for syntax errors. I was still able to deploy and execute code.